# Do mapping classes have gonality?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, algebraic-curves

(This question was discussed by people at the PCMI workshop on moduli spaces, without any clear resolution, so I thought I'd throw it open to MO.)

The hyperelliptic mapping class group is (by definition) the subgroup of mapping classes commuting with an involution.  Not all mapping classes are hyperelliptic.  In algebraic geometry, we would say that the map $H_g \to M_g$ (where $H_g$ is the moduli space of hyperelliptic genus $g$ curves) does not induce a surjection on fundamental groups.

What about the trigonal locus $T_g$, parametrizing genus-g curves endowed with a degree-3 map to $\mathbb{P}^1$?  Does the map $T_g \to M_g$ induce a surjection, or a finite-index inclusion on fundamental groups?  (We do know that $\pi_1(T_g)$, like $\pi_1(H_g)$, surjects onto $Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$, or at least we know its image is Zariski dense; I'm not sure whether we know its image is finite-index, now that I think of it.)

In topology, we would ask the following question: (equivalent?  if not, close to it)  Let $\phi$ be a surjection from the free group on $k$ generators to $S_3$, sending each generator to the class of a transposition, and let $\Gamma$ be the (finite-index) subgroup of the $k$-strand braid group consisting of elements which stabilize $\phi$ under left composition.  The realization of $\phi$ as a degree-$3$ simply branched cover of a sphere yields a map from $\Gamma$ to some mapping class group $\Gamma_g$, whose image is what we might call the trigonal genus-g mapping class group; the question is whether this is a *proper* subgroup.

More generally, one could define the gonality of a mapping class $f$ to be the minimal $d$ such that $[f]$ lies in the image of the fundamental group of the space of $d$-gonal curves of genus $g$.  Is this an interesting invariant?  (i.e. if it is always 2 or 3 it is not so interesting.)

Comment: JSE -- I've taken the liberty of latex'ing the unlatexed formulas. This is an interesting question, but it was a bit difficult to read.

Comment: algori -- you are very kind not to mention that in addition to my failure to TeX, I failed to notice that you already asked a morally equivalent question a year and a half ago!  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14179/trigonal-loci-in-teichmueller-spaces

Comment: JSE -- thanks. The questions are indeed similar. Hopefully, yours will be luckier than the one I asked.

Comment: Don't fundamental groups of algebraic varieties carry mixed Hodge structures?  If so, perhaps you can use the fact that the hyperelliptic and trigonal loci are Zariski open in projective rational varieties to show that these Hodge structures have "smaller coniveau" than the Hodge structure for all of $M_g$.

Comment: Jason -- some caution is needed when talking about MHS's on fundamental groups. For example, $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}^*\times \mathbb{C}^*$ and also of an elliptic curve.

Comment: I am not quite sure what the caution is about.  Of course the MHS on the fundamental group of a variety depends on the variety.  Even if two different varieties have the same fundamental group, the associated MHS's can be different.  

I guess the real question is whether the MHS on the fundamental group of a variety is covariant for morphisms of varieties.  If so, then since the trigonal locus is unirational (rational?), its MHS should be "special".  And you can use that to try to prove it cannot surject onto the MHS of $M_g$.

Comment: I'm not sure that your characterization is quite right. A branched cover is a cover in all but a finite number of points. Removing these points, you get a cover of a punctured sphere. This is determined by a homomorphism to $S_3$, however I don't see why some punctures can't map to an element of order 3 (clearly they can't be trivial, or the cover wouldn't branch over those points)? 

Comment: Also, to clarify, the trigonal locus is a map of a finite cover of moduli space of an n-punctured sphere (decorated by a homomorphism to S_3) to the moduli space of a genus g surface. This map might not be an embedding, there may be multiple ways that certain surfaces may branch. Also, according to my other comment, there may be multiple components of the moduli space of branchings. I was wondering if you wanted to consider the image in the mapping class group of the corresponding cover of moduli space, or do you want to consider the fundamental group of the total trigonal locus? 

Comment: Agol -- yeah, that's why I hedged on "equivalent."  Two comments.  1.  If the genus is at all large, the trigonal map is unique; 2. The trigonal genus-g curves which are simply branched (all monodromy of order 2) are parametrized an open subvariety U_g of the whole trigonal locus T_g; the map from pi_1(U_g) to pi_1(M_g) factors through pi_1(T_g) -> pi_(M_g) so if the former is surjective, the latter is too. 

Comment: Ok, that helps clarify things. One issue that makes this trickier than the hyperelliptic case is that the hyperelliptic maps of moduli spaces are $\pi_1$-injective (in fact, give isometric embeddings), whereas the $U_g$ map is not an isometric embedding (although I'm not sure if anything is in the kernel of $\pi_1$). If it were $\pi_1$-injective, then I would suspect it couldn't be surjective. 

Comment: Yes, that's right -- Joe Harris explained this to me at PCMI -- you can see that pi_1(U_g) can't actually be the SAME as pi_1(M_g) because it doesn't have enough finite subgroups (there are lots of finite groups that can be Aut(G) for a genus-g curve but not for a trigonal genus-g curve.)  So injective implies not surjective.

Answer (score 6):

it seems that your question about the possible surjectivity of the map

$$\pi_1(T_g) \to \pi_1(M_g)$$

has been recently answered positively in http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7399 (see the very first page of the paper.